# Ubuntu freezes on startup at login screen

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, 17.10

I am currently dual booting with Windows 10 on this laptop. When I boot, Ubuntu freezes at the login screen. Nothing I have found provided a long term/permanent solution for me. I believe it is to do with my dual graphics (Intel on-board graphics and Nvidia GTX 970) having some sort of conflict. I have tried booting with nomodeset and nouveua modeset both to 0 but it is quite temperamental if it works or not.

I have had this problem with freezing or black screens on about 3 or 4 installations of different distributions so I am certain it is a hardware conflict issue.

How can I fix this freezing problem?

Comment: You could try booting to `Recovery` mode, and uninstall the Nvidia driver, reboot, and see if you can get past the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot in recovery mode by pressing left SHIFT or ESC, then switch from the NVIDIA drivers to the xserver-xorg-video drivers within the Driver Manager - then reboot. You could also try an earlier version of the NVIDIA driver.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)